# Converting Character to integer

Tags: python, python-3.x

Inputs: 99, 3.77, z, howdy

Below is the simple program which I can't get to work right on the end piece. This is using Python 3, which I don't have a choice in using.

```
user_int = int(input('Enter integer (32 - 126):\n'))

user_float = float(input('Enter float:\n'))
user_char = input('Enter character:\n')
user_string = input('Enter string:\n')

print(user_int, user_float, user_char, user_string)

print(user_string, user_char, user_float, user_int)
```

This is the portion that is giving me trouble, I'm doing as directed with chr() but it keeps failing. I've tried to make the variable itself chr but either way I get string cannot be integer error.

```
print(user_int, 'converted to a character is', chr(user_char))
```

This is the error provided:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/local/submission/main.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(user_int, 'converted to a character is', chr(user_char))
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

This is my class work, I'm not asking it to be done for me but idk which direction to go even the other Stack answers aren't helping me here.

To give more details on why i'm doing it this way this is what I've been instructed:
Extend to convert the integer to a character by using the 'chr()' function, and output that character. (Submit for 2 points, so 5 points total).

expected ouput:
Enter integer (32 - 126):
99
Enter float:
3.77
Enter character:
z
Enter string:
Howdy
99 3.77 z Howdy
Howdy z 3.77 99
99 converted to a character is c
```

Comment: Please edit your post to include the inputs you provided to test your code, that caused the observed error

Comment: chr() converts an integer to the associated character. You are not passing an integer to the function.

Comment: `print(user_int, 'converted to a character is', chr(user_char))`—Why are you trying to pass `user_char` to `chr` rather than `user_int`, as the print statement suggests?

Comment: `ord` is the python function that turns a character into it's ascii integer value.  `chr` turns a number into it's character string.

Comment: @VoNWooDSoN Unicode, not ASCII.

Comment: ASCII is UTF8, didn't you know?

Comment: @VoNWooDSoN who said anything about the input being ASCII?

Comment: @khelwood because i'm a damn idiot; I've been sitting on this for an hour now almost and you made me look at the way i was suppose to. I've been outta practice from taking a sabbatical for person stuff for almost 2 years

Comment: @MarkRansom "integer (32 - 126)" sure looks like ASCII to me.

Comment: This has been answered and I figured it out. This one is on me guys sorry.

Comment: @Barmar so maybe the program is intended to work only on ASCII, but the `ord` function doesn't care.  `ord('')` works just as well as `ord('A')`.  Claiming it only works with ASCII is misleading.

Comment: @VoNWooDSoN there are far too many people that believe everything they read and take things too literally.  Often those people end up confused and come back to SO to clear their confusion.  If being pedantic can prevent that, I'm all for it.